# awk compare and append the matches into another file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

i want to compare the 1st columns of two files. if there is a match print the corresponding value of the 1st and 2nd column from the 1st file to the 2nd file

file1
`apple,1,2`
`orange,2,3`
`pine,3,4`

file2
`apple,2,2`
`orange,4,5`

Desired output
`apple,2,2,1,2`
`orange,4,5,2,3`

i was able to find the matches by `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{_1[$1]++;next}_1[$1]' file2 file1` , but dont know how to append the file1 values into file2

Answer (score 2):

how about :

```
join -t',' file2 file1
```

if you love to do it with awk:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;sub(/^[^,]*,/,"",a[$1]);next}$1 in a{print $0 FS a[$1]}' f1 f2
```

Comment: thanks for the `awk` @kent, it would be great if you explain it. the join command is not working
`cat file2`
apple,2,2
orange,4,5
`cat file1`
apple,1,2
pine,3,43
orange,2,3 `join -t "," file2 file1` gives only apple,2,2,1,2 as result

Comment: @GanzRicanz it( the awk one) is pretty straightforward, which part you didn't get?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `join`:

```
join -t "," file2 file1
```

Or extend your `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{_1[$1]++;_2[$1]=FS $2 FS $3;next}_1[$1]{print $0 _2[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: thanks for the awk @mark, it would be great if you explain it. the join command is not working cat file2 apple,2,2 orange,4,5 cat file1 apple,1,2 pine,3,43 orange,2,3 join -t "," file2 file1 gives only apple,2,2,1,2 as result

Comment: The awk is just like yours except it stores fields 2 & 3 separated by your field separator (FS) in array _2[] as well. Then, when it prints, it prints the whole line from file2 ($0) and fields 2 & 3 that it saved from file1.

Comment: I'm surprised the "join" command doesn't work. Have you got weird characters in your file? Try running "cat -vet file[12]" and look for ^M. If you have some, try running "dos2unix file1" etc.